# bulk email sending with an attachment using mutt

Tags: mutt

A friend of mine who uses Windows needs to send an email to a few hundred people regularly. A simple greeting line and a PDF attachment (not a spam, nothing illegal!).

Until recently she managed to just use bcc, but now emails are bouncing back undelivered. I thought to help her do that task in Linux using Mutt. But I'm not very familiar with CLI to write a script myself. Could someone help with a script to help her?

She usually writes just a simple text greeting, a PDF file as an attachment. I thought to use a file with the addresses.

On the Internet I found a script like that:

```
a="address1@gmail.com, address2@gmail.com"
mutt -s "subject" -a file.pdf -- $a
```

Would it work with about 1000 addresses or is it better to use some kind if a loop?:

```
for i in ...
```

And here I'm stuck! I'm not really familiar with that stuff!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First you had better check the bounce messages to ensure that it isn't her provider limiting the number of people to whom an email can be sent!  It's common that the threshold is 100 addresses (recipients), but provider rules vary.  If that's the case, you will need one of the many bulk-mailing services, or send them in <100-recipient groups.  Sending bulk emails often can also land one on various block lists, which then depend on the recipient servers' use of <whatever> list(s) and getting the sending address whiteliested with the recipients' servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Perl script for this purpose, so I can send emails periodically without annoying my relaying service. Below is a cleaned-up version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                              

while (<>) {                                                                                                                                 
    chomp;                                                                                                                                   
    $email_address = $_;                                                                                                                     
#    print "Email address: " . $email_address . "\n";                                                                                        
    $command = "cat message.txt | mutt " . $email_address . " -F ~/.mutt_config -s \"Here goes the subject\"" -a attachment.pdf;                            
#    print $command . "\n";                                                                                                                  
    system( $command );                                                                                                                      
    sleep( 30 );                                                                                                                             
}
```

The input is a text file containing one email address per line, and you pass it as a command line argument.

Then you can have a message file (message.txt), an attachment file (attachment.pdf) and a special mutt configuration file so you can customize From, Reply-to, etc.